# airflow SSH operator error, unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python, ubuntu, ssh, airflow

I'm trying to run a DAG, however it fails with this error in the log:

```
 ERROR - SSH operator error: exec_command() got an unexpected keyword argument 'environment'
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

For me this was a Paramiko version issue, this appears to be a bug that was fixed in versions after 2.1.0. A simple

Answer (score 0):

Could not find the answer to this but ran

```
pip uninstall apache-airflow
sudo pip install apache-airflow
```

and it workeed